# How to prevent fountain pen ink from evaporating during winter months?

Tags: tools, writing-instruments

While using a fountain pen, I noticed that the ink dries up much faster during the winter. I read that it is because of home heaters, which dry up moisture in air and hence causes the ink to evaporate.

Since using heaters is inevitable, and moving to warmer climate isn't feasible, my question is that how can we prevent or slow down the ink evaporation?

I have thought to put the pen in a [ziploc bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziploc) so that it can be sealed, but it is not a very trustworthy method.

Comment: Yes, ziplock bag, but with a damp cotton ball to provide the moisture. Or else a pen that seals better when you cap it.

Comment: @DPT I appreciate your comment. I was thinking on the same lines about ziploc, however adding a damp cotton ball may resolve the issue but it might make the pen wet. Regarding the seal, I think that might not be possible because all pen caps I've seen, have holes in them.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly contrary to intuition -- *write more*.  The faster you use up the ink, the more often you'll refill (and presumably clean) the pen, and the less trouble you'll have with drying up.

If you're going to put it away for more than a week or so, empty it, clean it, dry it, and store it closed and dry -- then treat it like a new pen when you're ready to ink it again.

Comment: I want to do this too _write more_ but the present world's dilemma is that there isn't much to write, or [most of the paper](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/41605/8388) isn't good enough.

Comment: That's a separate problem,  There was a question related to that recently.

Comment: Yes, **I** asked that question :)

Answer (score 3):

Get a humidifier and a hygrometer. Try to keep the humidity in your home between 30-45%. Not only will it help keep your pen from drying out it can also help reduce your heating cost. Moist air retains heat better than dry air allowing you to lower your thermostat but still stay warm.

Comment: I didn't know that moist air retains heat better. But regardless, keeping air moist also addresses a lot of other issues during cold months.